# X-RateLimit-Remaining higher than X-RateLimit-Limit in Laravel 5.2 API throttling

Tags: php, api, laravel, throttling

I'm creating a small API on Laravel 5.2 and decided to test the embedded throttling mechanism using cURL. The API limit was set to 10.

Basic test: run a GET request 11 times until I get a 429 response.

Well, it works, but I got a weird behavior. **The X-RateLimit-Remaining is 11, even higher than X-RateLimit-Limit**! I expected it to stay at 0 until the Retry-After period is over.

Questions: is it a bug? Is there any reason to treat this behavior as expected?

I tried to reproduce this problem, but it didn't kick in again.

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 7000 (#0)
> GET /company HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: localhost:7000
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
< Date: Wed, 11 May 2016 12:47:33 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu)
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-RateLimit-Limit: 10
< X-RateLimit-Remaining: 11
< Retry-After: 52
< Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI...; expires=Wed, 11-May-2016 14:47:34 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
< Content-Length: 18
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using?

Comment: Laravel 5.2 with API middleware